# Pandas Dataframe Line Plot: Show Random Markers

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I often have dataframes with many obervations and want to have a quick glance at the data using a line plot.

The problem is that the colors of the colormap are either repeated over X observations or hard to distinguish e.g. in case of sequential colormaps.

So my idea was to add random markers to the line plot which is where I got stuck.

Here's an example with one markerstyle:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dataframe with random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 8))

# plot
df.plot(kind='line', marker='d')
plt.show()
```

which delivers:

[image]

Is it also possible to draw a (random) marker for each line?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please accept the answer from Jarana. It is the much better option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we need to choose random marker. It could be done via `matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle.markers` dictionary which contains all available markers. Also markers means 'nothing', starting with 'tick' and 'caret' should be dropped Some more [information](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html) abour markers. Let's make list with valid markers and then random choose from them how many we need for plotting DataFrame or you could use second option with `filled_markers`:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

# create valid markers from mpl.markers
valid_markers = ([item[0] for item in mpl.markers.MarkerStyle.markers.items() if 
item[1] is not 'nothing' and not item[1].startswith('tick') 
and not item[1].startswith('caret')])

# use fillable markers
# valid_markers = mpl.markers.MarkerStyle.filled_markers

markers = np.random.choice(valid_markers, df.shape[1], replace=False)
```

For example:

```
In [146]: list(markers )
Out[146]: ['H', '^', 'v', 's', '3', '.', '1', '_']
```

Then for markers you could plot your dataframe, and set markers for each line via `set_marker` method. Then you could add legend to your plot:

```
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2016)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 8))

ax = df.plot(kind='line')
for i, line in enumerate(ax.get_lines()):
    line.set_marker(markers[i])

# for adding legend
ax.legend(ax.get_lines(), df.columns, loc='best')
```

Original:

[image]

Modified:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It would be cool if this was implemented in pandas so that one could just use a flag like "random_markers=True". But this already helped me.

Comment: @CordKaldemeyer yes, it's could be a good reason for feature request.

Comment: @CordKaldemeyer thanks for the request. I'm also finding that possible feature useful.

Answer (score 7):

`pandas` uses `matplotlib` as the default backend for plotting. To define a different marker and linestyle for each line, you can pass a `list` to the `style` parameter, where each value in the list follows the `fmt` convention from [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) (e.g. `'[marker][line][color]'`):

```
df.plot(style=['+-', 'o-', '.--', 's:'])
```

This can also include 1-letter color abbreviations

```
df.plot(style=['+-y','o-b','.--g','s:k'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code for plotting with random markers. You can also adjust the axis and legend sizes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from pandas import DataFrame

value1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] 
value2 = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
value3 = [8, 9, 10, 15, 20]

results1 = DataFrame({'SAC': value1, 'TD3': value2, 'DDPG': value3})
color_dict = {'SAC': '#FF0000', 'TD3': '#0000FF', 'DDPG': '#008000'}
# create valid markers from mpl.markers
valid_markers = ([item[0] for item in mpl.markers.MarkerStyle.markers.items() if
item[1] is not 'nothing' and not item[1].startswith('tick') and not item[1].startswith('caret')])
markers = np.random.choice(valid_markers, results1.shape[1], replace=False)
res1 = results1.plot(fontsize=10, linewidth=3, figsize=(10, 8), markersize=16, color=[color_dict.get(x, '#333333') for x in results1.columns])
for i, line in enumerate(res1.get_lines()):
  line.set_marker(markers[i])
plt.legend(fontsize=20, loc='lower right')
plt.xlabel("Episode", fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel("Rewards", fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]