# Pandas plotting multiple markers in a figure from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am currently plotting a dataframe of time series observations with 5 columns (i.e., 5 lines) using `matplotlib` on Jupyter. The code I am using is the following:

`df.plot(kind='line', markersize=10, marker='o')`

I would like to have that each line has a different marker. Therefore, I tried the following:

`df.plot(kind='line', markersize=10, marker={'s','o', 'D', 'P', '^'})`

but it returns an error that `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`.

How can I make sure that each data frame's column has a different marker in the above code? I am new to Matplotlib so sorry about the silly question.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that you are doing pandas plotting instead of matplotlib plotting? Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes, is there a way to assign markers to different columns?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54426351/7758804) of the duplicate is the better option.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney agree! I didn't know there is such option in pandas plotting.

Comment: @Karina neither did I, but it seems obvious now, since pandas.DataFrame.plot is using matplotlib as the backend. You can also add the colors in style `df.plot(style=['y+-','bo-','g.--','ks:', 'r'])` as long as they have a 1 letter abbreviation.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
y = []
for i in range(5):
    y.append(np.random.rand(10))    
marker = ['s','o', 'D', 'P', '^']
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(5):
    df[f'y{i}'] = y[i]
ax = df.plot.line()
for i, line in enumerate(ax.get_lines()):
    line.set_marker(marker[i])
```

Output is:

[image]

I can think of a better practice using `matplotlib` plotting instead of `pandas` plotting though...

Comment: Would you share your  better approach with `matplotlib`? @Karina